# findPose() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, pycharm, opencv, mediapipe

```
import cv2 

import time

import mediapipe as mp

def main():

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    pTime = 0  # Previous time
    global img
    detector = poseDetector

    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()

        detector.findPose()
        cTime = time.time()
        print(cTime, pTime)
        fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
        pTime = cTime

        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (70, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_COMPLEX, 3, (255, 0, 0), 3)

        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)


class poseDetector():

    def __init__(self, mode=True, complexity=1, smooth=True, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.complexity = complexity
        self.smooth = smooth
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon

        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
        self.mpPose = mp.solutions.pose
        self.pose = self.mpPose.Pose(self.mode, self.complexity, self.smooth,
                                     self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)

    def findPose(self, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        results = self.pose.process(imgRGB)
        if results.pose_landmarks and draw:
            self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, results.pose_landmarks, self.mpPose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    global img
    main()
```

I'm getting this message in Pycharm
Earlier when I had not declared img as global it used to be img as missing argument.
I've searched a lot it says that pycharm doesn't take arguments apart from list, tuples....
The source of code is from [Advanced computer vision](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01sAkU_NvOY&t=4708s). Timeline is somewhere 1hr 18min. Can you please help me

Comment: You need to instantiate `postDetector` i.e. `detector = poseDetector()` instead of `detector = poseDetector` which is done inside `main` method.

Comment: Also in Python 3, there's no need to write the empty parentheses in `class poseDetector():`

Answer (score 1):

As poseDetector() is a class and to make detector as an instance of this class here it requires a small change in def main() after global img as below:

```
detector = poseDetector()
```